# Navegar dentro de un iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Que tal amigos espero me puedan ayudar, tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy poniendo una pagina dentro de un iframe, pero quiero que todas las navegaciones que contenga la pagina se mantengan dentro de ese mismo iframe sin que abra una nueva pagina, quiero saber si esto es posible si no tengo el control de la pagina que estoy colocando en el iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Respuesta corta (tl;dr):**
Sí se puede, agregando el atributo `sandbox` al iframe.

**Respuesta larga:**
Una posible solución que html5 ofrece es el modo sandbox para los `iframe`. Al estar como sandbox, algunas operaciones estarán restringidas y sólo podrán realizarse si se especifica en una variable. Ejemplos de estas operaciones ([puedes ver más en la definición de sandboxing](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#sandboxing)):

- comunicarse con el contenedor
- inicializar plugins
- crear nuevos contextos (← ésta es la parte que te interesa)
- mandar formularios
- bloquear la ejecución de scripts

Para poner un `iframe` en modo sandbox, tan sólo tienes que agregarle el atributo [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe#attr-sandbox). Lo puedes dejar vacío o agregar algunos permisos en modo de tokens:

- `allow-forms`: para permitir que se puedan enviar formularios dentro del `iframe`
- `allow-modals`: para permitir que se puedan abrir modales desde el contexto del `iframe`
- `allow-popups`: para permitir pop-ups, ventanas/pestañas nuevas, etc. Si no se indica, fallará sin dar ningún mensaje de error
- `allow-scripts`: para permitir que corra scripts
- `allow-presentation`: para permitir que el `iframe` inicie una sesión de presentación

Hay más posibles valores, aunque no todos aparece en la traducción al español de MDN enlazada arriba. Si te interesa el tema, puedes leer más en inglés en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) o en la [definición del W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-iframe-sandbox).

Así que sólo con poner el atributo `sandbox` ya la página del `iframe` no podrá abrir popups o nuevas pestañas/ventanas. Y si quieres darle permisos, puedes ver las opciones que te interesen para dárselas. Tan simple como esto:

```
<iframe src="http://otrodominio.com/" sandbox>
</iframe>
```

> **AVISO**: El atributo `sandbox` está más o menos extendido y no deberías tener problemas de compatibilidad, pero no funcionará en versiones antiguas de IE (IE9 e inferiores) y algunos de los tokens pueden no funcionar en todos los navegadores.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro por tu apoyo, tengo una duda ya intente agregando el atributo sandbox, y efectivamente bloquea que habra una nueva ventana sin embargo tampo abre la ventana sobre el iframe bloquea totalmente la funcionalidad (navegación), hay algun modo de que esta navegación siga funcionando sin necesidad de que abra una nueva ventana.

Comment: @Eduardo ¿A qué te refieres con "_sin embargo tampo abre la ventana sobre el iframe bloquea totalmente la funcionalidad (navegación)_"? He probado a poner enlaces con y sin `target` y los enlaces sin `target` se abren sin problemas dentro del iframe, sólo bloqueando los que se abrirían fuera.

Comment: en efecto como mencionas al final "sólo bloqueando los que se abrirían fuera", digamos que esos enlaces que abren en una nueva ventana no quiero que lo hagan de ese modo si no que se abran dentro del mismo iframe, no se si me haga falta contemplar algún valor del sandbox para que esto funcione de ese modo.