# ¿Cómo editar una página externa a través de un iframe sin acceso denegado?

Tags: php, jquery

El siguiente código me captura un sitio web idénticamente.

```
<?php
    $URL = "http://domain.com/embed.html";

    $domain = file_get_contents($URL);

    echo $domain;
?>
```

Pero que parámetros o filtros debo agregarle para obtener solo cierta parte de un sitio y poder eliminar o reemplazar enlaces y contenidos, bloquear ejecución de `scripts`*.

Encontré también un ejemplo empleado con `jQuery` para editar una página externa a través de un `iframe` sin acceso denegado, etc.

Pero, no entiendo en sí, como funciona específicamente, ¿Que valores se deben emplear para eliminar o remplazar enlaces y contenidos bloquear ejecución de `scripts`, pueden explicarme?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
cleanit = setInterval ( "cleaning()", 500 );
});

function cleaning(){
if($('#frametest').contents().find('.selector').html() == "somthing"){
    clearInterval(cleanit);
    $('#selector').contents().find('.Link').html('ideate tech');
}
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe name="frametest" id="frametest" src="example.com" ></iframe>
```

> He observado [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117106/navegar-dentro-de-un-iframe) atributos nuevos de `HTML5`, que se pueden hacer directo en un `iframe` pero de esa manera no lo deseo en ciertas partes se congela todo sin mostrarme nada.

Comment: podrías dar un ejemplo de lo que cargaría en el iframe y qué cosas te interesan y cuales eliminar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para lo que intentas hacer te sugiero algunas expresiones regulares que te pueden ayudar, sin embargo, para casos mas específicos que requieras, deberás identificar que expresión regular se adapta a tus necesidades:

Una vez obtenido el contenido de la web con:

```
$URL = "http://domain.com";
$domain = file_get_contents($URL);
```

Para poder eliminar ciertas etiquetas puedes aplicar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886740/php-remove-javascript):

```
$domain = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', "", $domain);//Remueve los Script
$domain = preg_replace('@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu', "", $domain);//Remueve los head
$domain = preg_replace('@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu', "", $domain);//Remueve el css
$domain = preg_replace('@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu', "", $domain);//Remueve los noscript
```

Si deseas reemplazar algún texto especifico puedes usar expresiones regulares o la función de php str_replace aplicada a la variable $domain (http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

Y para poder reemplazar links (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573553/php-file-get-contents-replace-all-urls-in-all-a-href-links)

```
$content = explode("\n", $domain);
for($i=0;count($content)>$i;$i++)
    {
        if(preg_match('/<a href=/', $content[$i]))
            {
                list($Gone,$Keep) = explode("href=\"", trim($content[$i]));
                list($Keep,$Gone) = explode("\">", $Keep);
                $domian = strtr($domian, array( "$Keep" => "http://www.replaceSite.com/", ));
            }
    }

echo $domain;
```

Espero te pueda servir.

Answer (score 4):

Si lo he entendido bien, intentas visualizar una (parte o modificación) de una página web dentro de otra tuya.

Para ello una de las alternativas que propones es poner un iframe y modificar el contenido mediante javascript.

Si tu página y la página del iframe no comparten el mismo dominio, esto **no** puede funcionar nunca. El motivo es que sería un agujero de seguridad enorme.

Ejemplo: Dispongo de una página web en midominio.com y agrego un iframe que apunte a gmail. Si no existiera la *política de mismo origen*, podría modificar la web de gmail de forma y manera que cuando un usuario se logase a gmail con el iframe de mi página web, podría conocer y guardar el password utilizado. O incluso, aunque no guardase el password podría leer/acceder a los correos una vez se hubiera logado.

La restricción se aplica también a la inversa. Desde un iframe no puedo acceder a datos del padre si éste no está en el mismo dominio.

Más detalle:

http://notasjs.blogspot.com/2013/09/politica-del-mismo-origen-same-origin.html

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_del_mismo_origen

Una posible solución a tu problema es utizar lo que has comentado de file_get_contents. Pero te en cuenta que:

Así no estás recuperando una página web completa, si no únicament el html. Así que si por ejemplo quisieras recuperar las imágenes, deberías examinar el html recuperado en busca de etiquetas `<img>` (por ejemplo), y buscar su `src` para de esta manera hacer una nueva petición y recuperar una imagen.

Además, es posible que la página web que intentas recuperar utilice ajax para mostrar/modificar parte del contenido. Con lo que con file_get_content solo obtendrías el estado base/inicial de la web.

Si el contenido que te interesa se obtiene via ajax, deberías inspeccionar las distintas peticiones http que hace la página y hacer tú una petición para cada una de ellas.

También comentar que una vez has recuperado el texto de una web, puedes hacer búsquedas y sustituciones con la instrucción [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php). preg_replace puede utilizar [expresiones regulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) para búsquedas y sustituciones complejas.

Aunque quizás una mejor alternativa sería el uso de un [parseador html](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html)

Comment: Oscar, @otto, la recompensa termina en dos horas. Hay alguna evaluación de las respuestas? Gracias.